# Graphene - GraphQL : 'Request' object has no attribute 'context'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, graphql, graphene-python

I'm working on a simple GraphQL Flask API and I'm implementing a simple find user resolver. This is my `schema.py`

```
import graphene
from graphene import relay
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyObjectType, SQLAlchemyConnectionField
from models import db_session, Users as UsersModel, Channel as ChannelModel, Video as VideoModel

class Users(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = UsersModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Channel(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ChannelModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()
    users = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(Users)
    find_user = graphene.Field(Users, name = graphene.String())
    all_user = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(Users)

    def resolve_find_user(self, args, context, info):
        query = Users.get_query(context)
        name = args.get('name')
        return query.get(name)
```

I'm using `graphene` 2.0 and the code returns an error of `"message": "resolve_find_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'",` After some Googling, it looks like that is a [major change](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/542) in `graphene` that change the way resolver works.

I went through the `UPGRADE-v2.0.md` and change things accordingly. The resolver looks like this now.

```
# def resolve_find_user(self, info, name):
#     query = Users.get_query(info.context)
#     return query.get(name)
```

Now, the keyword argument disappears but I'm having a new issue. The error is `"message": "'Request' object has no attribute 'context'",`. Now I'm confused because I thought `info.context` should have worked but apparently it is not. Any idea about how to fix this context issue? This is my first time working on GraphQL and any help is really appreciated!

Edit: It's looks like `type(info)` is a `<class 'graphql.execution.base.ResolveInfo'>` and `type(info.context)` is `<class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy'>`. Should the `context` be the SQLAlchemy context?

Comment: It seems like your code should work.  What are `type(info.context)`  and `type(info)` ?

Comment: Yeah, I updated my post. I know that `SQLAlchemy` can be quite picky with it context. Should the `info.context` be something related to that?

Comment: I haven't used this with Flask but I inspected my Django types for a comparison.  `type(info)` : `<class 'graphql.execution.base.ResolveInfo'>` ; `type(info.context)` : `<class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest'>` .  I don't think that context should be related to SQLAlchemy -- it should be a representation of the HTTP request in Flask, whatever that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 2.0 of graphene your solution would be like this

```
def resolve_find_user(self, info, name):
  query = Users.get_query(info)
  return query.filter(UsersModel.name == name).first()
```

For more information [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/UPGRADE-v1.0.md)